# My Sendmail is still using esmtp instead of aws email in Ec2 instance

Tags: linux, centos, amazon-ec2, sendmail

I have followed all steps here:

- http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/scripts-mtas-sendmail.html

This is my `sendmail.mc`:

```
FEATURE(`mailertable')dnl
MAILER_DEFINITIONS
Maws-email, P=/opt/third-party/amazon/ses-send-email.pl, F=mDFMuXn, U=amazonuser, S=EnvFromSMTP/HdrFromSMTP, R=EnvToSMTP, A=ses-send-email.pl -r -k /opt/third-party/amazon/aws-credentials -e   https://email.us-east-1.amazonaws.com   -f $f $u
MASQUERADE_AS(mydomain.com)dnl
FEATURE(masquerade_envelope)dnl
FEATURE(masquerade_entire_domain)dnl

MAILER(smtp)dnl
MAILER(procmail)dnl
dnl MAILER(cyrusv2)dnl
```

If I do this:

```
# sudo sendmail -bv johny2376494@gmail.com
johny2376494@gmail.com... deliverable: mailer esmtp, host gmail.com., user johny2376494@gmail.com
```

But output should be:

```
mailer awsemail
```

what should I do? I have followed this as well:

- https://forums.aws.amazon.com/message.jspa?messageID=227777

Comment: You've definitely also added the entry to the /etc/mail/mailertable to force all outbound mail to use the new `aws-email` mailer and rebuild the mailertable database? (steps 6-8 in the docs)

Comment: @USDMatt : Could you turn your comment into answer?

Comment: @USDMatt , now i am confused , amazon docs says to create file `/etc/mailmailertable` where i have put entry but they are not using that anywhere. chk the step 7 here http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/scripts-mtas-sendmail.html

Comment: @USDMatt , i think amazon idiots have a typo there. i wasted 10 hours on that file should be `/etc/mail/mailertable` not `/etc/mailmailertable`

Comment: Yes they get it wrong in steps 6 & 7 by the look of it, then have the right file path in the makemap command

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question shows the additions to add the AWS mailer to Sendmail, but it doesn't look like anything it actually configured to use that mailer.

Looking at the Amazon docs, they require updating `/etc/mail/mailertable` to direct mail for all domains (`.`) via the new mailer. However, at the time of writing they have a typo in a few steps and incorrectly call the file `/etc/mailmailertable`.

Assuming there are no other issues (I've never used AWS myself) configuring the `mailertable` file correctly and rebuilding the associated database file should cause Sendmail to use the AWS mailer for all outbound mail.